# Cannot get certain fields in MySQL with group by query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following query (and tried a lot of variations of it)
:

```
select housedata.housecode, housedata.name, min((pergroup + (perguest *  GREATEST((2 - guests_included),0)))) as mincalculated 
from housedata
inner join availabilitydata 
where housedata.housecode = availabilitydata.housecode 
and  datediff(departure, arrival) = 7 group by housedata.housecode
```

This works fine, but I need more fields from table availabilitydata. As soon as I try to add those MySQL complains:

> [42000][1055] Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'houses.availabilitydata.arrival' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I can add the field to the group by but then I get more then one result because the availabilitydata are multiple rows.

How can I limit this to one row per house, namely the row from which min((pergroup + (perguest * GREATEST((2 - guests_included),0)))) is gotten.

tables:

```
create table availabilitydata
(
  arrival              date        not null,
  departure            date        not null,
  housecode            varchar(32) not null,
  pergroup             float       null,
  pergroupexcldiscount float       null,
  perguest             float       null,
  guests_included      tinyint     null,
  primary key (housecode, arrival, departure)
);

create table housedata
(
  housecode       varchar(32) not null
    primary key,
  name            tinytext    null
);
```

Data should  come out like this, but with the date column added:

```
344323  Wienerwaltz 680.530029296875
434300  Wald    882.7899780273438
943843  Chalet Miquel   630.8300170898438
```

Comment: Yes, what you are doing isn't standard SQL. MySQL can allow it if you change the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` parameter, but that is not a good idea. You should show exactly your data and how you want it to be returned, then we can help you with a proper query.

Comment: Ok, hope this is ok then.

Comment: There are multiple rows from `availabilitydata` per group. MySQL doesn't know which one you want to select. So the error message could be translated to "I don't know what you want" - Because you are not saying it. And we can't help, because you are not saying it us either.

Comment: I want one indeed, and I don't care too much. The first one (first date) would be great

Comment: @ThomasG That join condition is in the WHERE clause. IMHO bad practice, but technically the same as ON clause.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel right didnt even thought to check the where clause, shame on me

Comment: "I want one indeed, and I don't care too much" and "but I care about the relation between the price and the date" somehow don't fit together.

Comment: But let me make a guess: You want the row returned from which you get the `min((pergroup + (perguest *  GREATEST((2 - guests_included),0))))` value. If that is correct - that should be statet in your question.

Comment: Sorry, that is because of the answer below; there the relation between price and date gets lost because of getting min() of both date and price and then coming from different rows. The I don't care much is about a row that has the price and the date that originated in one row in table availabilitydate.

Comment: Expanded the question to make it clear which row I would like returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
select h.housecode
     , hh.name
     , pergroup + (perguest *  GREATEST((2 - guests_included),0)) as mincalculated
     -- select any column from a (availabilitydata)
from housedata h
inner join availabilitydata a on a.housecode = h.housecode 
where (a.housecode, a.arrival, a.departure) = (
    select a2.housecode, a2.arrival, a2.departure
    from availabilitydata a2
    where a2.housecode = h.housecode
      and datediff(a2.departure, a2.arrival) = 7
    order by a2.pergroup + (a2.perguest *  GREATEST((2 - a2.guests_included),0)) asc
    limit 1
)
```

In the correlated subquery you will get the primary key (`a.housecode, a.arrival, a.departure`) of the row with minimum calculated value. In the outer query you select only the row from `availabilitydata` with the same primary key.

Note that if two rows have the same calculated min value, you will get both of them. If you don't want both, you should define which one you want in the ORDER BY clause (eg. adding the full primary key):

```
order by a2.pergroup + (a2.perguest *  GREATEST((2 - a2.guests_included),0)) asc
    , a2.arrival
    , a2.departure
```

#### Update

The above solution doesn't seem to perform well. But if your version supports window functions, you can also use the following query:

```
select *
from (
    select housedata.housecode
         , housedata.name
         , pergroup + (perguest *  GREATEST((2 - guests_included),0)) as mincalculated
         , row_number() over (
             partition by housedata.housecode
             order by pergroup + (perguest *  GREATEST((2 - guests_included),0)) asc
         ) rn
         , availabilitydata.arrival
         -- select any other column from availabilitydata
    from housedata
    inner join availabilitydata on housedata.housecode = availabilitydata.housecode 
    where datediff(departure, arrival) = 7
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This is very slow (didn't even finish after a minute or more) if I have either two of the orders in the subquery.  The availability table has 80+ million records, the housedata table 20k. Can I make that faster somehow? Without the order it's fast.

Comment: @Maarten - How long does your original query take?

Comment: That is about 500 milli seconds. I have to add that at the moment both tables are a lot smaller even because I haven't imported a large dataset for development

Comment: I don't get it. Did you test my query on the large data, but your query on the small data? Or did my query not finish on the small data either?

Comment: The set is like this now: 1724548 rows for availabilitydata and 383 rows for housedata. That is my smaller set, and my 500 milliseconds and your not finishing query are both on that set.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: 8.0.15 homebrew on osx

Comment: @Maarten - Sorry, will have a look at it later. Need test data - so I don't need to guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189310/discussion-between-maarten-and-paul-spiegel).

Comment: in the end the updated version worked, but is still too slow for my usecase (millions of records in availabilitydata. Setting it as the working solution as it does do what was required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an aggregate function on the columns (fields) that you add to the SQL: those which are not aggregated should (in standard SQL, but mySQL accept the SQL anyway, depending on the sql_mode setting) be listed in the GROUP BY columns.

In conclusion, if you want to add `availabilitydata` table columns and you don't mind about which from multiple records in the same group show, you should use `MIN(availabilitydata.col1), MIN(availabilitydata.col2), ...` and always list all non aggregated columns in the GROUP BY statement:

```
select housedata.housecode, 
       housedata.name,
       min(availabilitydata.col1) as  availabilitydata_col1_min,
       min(availabilitydata.col2) as  availabilitydata_col2_min,
       ...,
       min((pergroup + (perguest *  GREATEST((2 - guests_included),0)))) as mincalculated 
from housedata
inner join availabilitydata 
where housedata.housecode = availabilitydata.housecode 
and  datediff(departure, arrival) = 7 
group by housedata.housecode,housedata.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I care about the relation between the price and the date, and that is indeed lost with your solution.

Comment: @Maarten you need to group by the date too, instead of use MIN aggregate function, and you will get multiple records. But isn't it what you do not want initially?

Comment: Yes multiple rows, but *one* per house